# Personal website deployment error: bin/deploy: line 2: $'\r': command not found

Tags: github-pages, jekyll-theme

My personal website was put on github.io, powered by [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) with [al-folio theme](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio).

Normally, if I want to make some changes, I will first type `docker-compose up` to test on local machine, then use git operations to deploy it online.

Recently, however, I've encounter some problems. The deployment on local machine is successful as usual, but when I use `git push origin master` to deploy it online, error occurs:

```
Run yes | bash bin/deploy --verbose  --src master --deploy gh-pages
bin/deploy: line 2: $'\r': command not found
bin/deploy: line 4: $'\r': command not found
bin/deploy: line 6: $'\r': command not found
bin/deploy: line 9: $'\r': command not found
bin/deploy: line 11: $'\r': command not found
bin/deploy: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
bin/deploy: line 15: `    case $key in
'
yes: standard output: Broken pipe
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

I have never seen anything like this. I try to google the problem, only to find something about different file format between linux and windows, e.g. to represent newline, windows uses `\r\n` while linux simply uses `\n`.

I don't know what happened: GitHub Pages is power by Jekyll, everytime the deployment is automatically done by github, my job is simply push the code to github. What can I do now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)